# Selecting MAX value for one column based on two other columns with one column having MAX value

Tags: mysql, case

I have a table data as below, that comes from different tables. I want to take the maximum value from 4th column only if 3rd column has value 'debt' AND 1st `column(DATE)` has maximum value. The final value is based on `MAX(DATE)` rather than `MAX(PRICE)`. so in simple language it comes this way

```
IF(MAX(DATE) && TYPE = 'debt'){
   MAX(PRICE);
}
```

Here is the image view of data available.

[image]

and the current query I am using is below

```
SELECT
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' AND RECEIPTS.DATENEW THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) AS TAKENDEBT,
    (CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) AS GIVENDEBT,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' THEN RECEIPTS.DATENEW END) AS TAKENDATE,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN RECEIPTS.DATENEW END) AS GIVENDATE,
    (MAX(CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END) + SUM((CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN PAYMENTS.TOTAL END))) AS DUE,        
    CASE WHEN PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt' OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid' THEN CUSTOMERS.NAME END AS CUSTOMER 
FROM RECEIPTS
    INNER JOIN TICKETS ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
    INNER JOIN PAYMENTS ON RECEIPTS.ID = PAYMENTS.RECEIPT
    INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS ON TICKETS.CUSTOMER = CUSTOMERS.ID
WHERE
    (PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debt'
    OR PAYMENTS.PAYMENT = 'debtpaid')
GROUP BY CUSTOMER
ORDER BY DUE DESC
```

which gives me the output as shown below with red circle, while I need the value in green circle. That means it's getting value based on MAX(PRICE) while I need on based of MAX(DATE) then MAX(PRICE) because there can be multiple values for same date.

[image]

AND PLEASE DON'T ASK ME TO PUT DATA IN FIDDLE THING, ITS A MESS OF DATABASE I MANAGED TO HAVE THIS QUERY AND NOW WANT TO BE ON THE SAME STRUCTURE. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

Try a solution similar to:

```
SELECT date, max(price) FROM yourTable 
  WHERE payment='debt' AND date = ( SELECT max(date) From yourTable)
  GROUP BY date
```

or

```
SELECT date ,max(price) FROM yourTable
  WHERE payment='debt'
  GROUP BY date
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Not in condition to use subquery, shall be a great mess. As I said want to keep the structure of the query on the same way with CASE statement.